# VS 2010: why sequence diagram has different design/style in two different projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sequence-diagram

I can't find any properties or whatsoever to specify how my shapes must look. And I get back two different results. This is from the modeling project I have:

[image]

And this one from the Class Library project:

[image]

Does the type of the project make it different??!

Comment: I found one interesting difference in properties of the schema - `Mode`. For the first one it's `UML` and for the second one it's `Dot Net`. But I can't change it.

Comment: Some posts from MS PMs: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/thread/2dca7179-7b14-4642-9f80-a0f80f77215f?prof=required